# Inner Join seems to return too many lines

Tags: mysql, sql

Why my `inner join` returns more records than the biggest table of the query?

This query returns 69 899 records:

```
select count(*) 
  from table_1@a_connection dd 
 inner join table_2@a_connection pr 
    on dd."ProjectRef" = pr."ProjectRef"
```

While this query returns 29 486 records

```
select count(*)
  from table_1@a_connection
```

And this query return 179 records

```
select count(*)
  from table_2@a_connection
```

This two tables are queried using a dblink on a MySql database.

Comment: because of a one to many relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why my inner join returns more records than the biggest table of the
>   query?

Because either 1st table or 2nd table or both contain duplicate values in `ProjectRef` column.
Please take a look at this simple example to see what might be causing this situation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fcd040/3

```
select * from a;

| a_id | a_name |
|------|--------|
|    1 |     A1 |
|    1 |     A2 |
|    1 |     A3 |
```

---

```
select * from b;

| b_id | b_name |
|------|--------|
|    1 |     B1 |
|    1 |     B2 |
|    1 |     B3 |
```

---

```
select * from a
join b
on a.a_id = b.b_id;

| a_id | a_name | b_id | b_name |
|------|--------|------|--------|
|    1 |     A1 |    1 |     B1 |
|    1 |     A2 |    1 |     B1 |
|    1 |     A3 |    1 |     B1 |
|    1 |     A1 |    1 |     B2 |
|    1 |     A2 |    1 |     B2 |
|    1 |     A3 |    1 |     B2 |
|    1 |     A1 |    1 |     B3 |
|    1 |     A2 |    1 |     B3 |
|    1 |     A3 |    1 |     B3 |
```

This example shows why the result of the join can give you many more records than  contains the largest of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of rows that you expect to be returned:

```
select sum(dd.cnt * pr.cnt)
from (select "ProjectRef", count(*) as cnt
      from table_1@a_connection
      group by "ProjectRef"
     ) dd join 
     (select "ProjectRef", count(*) as cnt
      from table_2@a_connection
      group by "ProjectRef"
     ) pr
     on dd."ProjectRef" = pr."ProjectRef";
```

I'm pretty sure this will return 69,899.  You can examine the results of the subqueries to understand what is happening with duplicate project refs.